# How to import a module in another module from the same subpackage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

My package tree is as follows:-

```
My_package
    |
    +--__init__.py    (empty)
    +--mainfile.py
    +--main_modules
        |
        +--__init__.py    (empty)
        +--module1.py
        +--module2.py
```

The content of module2:-

```
class Wish:
    def greatings(self):
        print("Hello World!")

wish = Wish()
```

When I try to import wish from module2 in module1 as:-
Content of module1:-

```
from module2 import wish
```

There is no error.

But when I import both modules in mainfile.py,
Content of mainfile.py:-

```
from main_modules import module1
from main_modules import module2
```

An error occurs:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\amuly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PyProgs\Test package\main package\mainfile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main_modules import module1
  File "c:\Users\amuly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PyProgs\Test package\main package\main_modules\module1.py", line 1, in <module>       
    from module2 import wish
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module2'
```

This is the screenshot of the issue:-
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBX8H.png)

I have searched various related questions and tried all to my best but it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `module1` and `module2` are on the same package level, you can simply do this in `module1.py`:

`from module2 import wish`

To import `module2.wish` from `mainfile.py`, you can do this:

`from main_modules.module2 import wish`

EDIT - in `module1.py`, change the import statement to this:

`from main_modules.m2 import wish`

using `main_modules.m2` will help because the function calls are happening from `mainfile.py`. Hence, import statements in the subsequently called files will look at the imports relative to `mainfile.py`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: For some reason it not working. I already tried it!

Comment: @A.Paritosh - try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: That works but a new problem arose. I have edited my question.

Comment: @A.Paritosh , check the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `.` in `from .module2 import wish` because they're on the same package level (as @Sindhu Satish already pointed out).

In you `module1.py` file, you have to change your import statement into this: `from module2 import wish` for it to work.

I hope I could help you!

Comment: I have added ss of my issue. For some reason it is not working. I must be doing some mistake but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: New problem arose. When both modules imported in mainfile, module2 can not be imported in module1